# Как найти 3 самых больших числа из введенных пользователем?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Нужно вывести три самых больших числа, но я не понимаю как это сделать.

```
int buf;
int max;

for (int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i) {
    cout << "number " << i << ": ";
    cin >> buf;
    if (i == 1 || (i > 1 && buf > max)) {
        max = buf;
    }

}

cout << "Max: " << max;
```

Comment: Если массив отсортирован, то вывести 3 последних числа(логично не правда ли)

Comment: Прошу прошение, допустил ошибку. Так как сейчас быть?

Comment: Отсортировать массив(можно пузырьком) сделать цикл который будет начинать с конца и так что бы он сработал 3 раза (щас могу предложить код но будут костыли)

Comment: Хорошо, буду не против.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int Arr[20];

    for(int f=0; f <20; f++)
    {
        cin >> Arr[f];//ввод значений массива
    }
     for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { //сортировк
    for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
      if (Arr[j] > Arr[j + 1]) {
        int b = Arr[j]; 
        Arr[j] = Arr[j + 1]; 
        Arr[j + 1] = b; 
      }
    }
  }
  for(int z=19; z >= 17; z--)
  cout <<Arr[z]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы же в комментариях разумное предложение внесли, а код привели...

Comment: @MBo ну так наглядней )

Answer (score 14):

Для трёх чисел выгоднее всего, видимо, создать буфер на три наибольших элемента (по сути - очередь по приоритетам), положить первые числа в правильном порядке, а дальше проверять, не больше ли очередное число, чем наименьшее число в буфере. Если да, то вытеснять наименьшее число, и вставлять новое в нужное место.

Comment: Смешная ситуация получилась с вопросом :) принятый ответ +1 ваш +12 :)

Comment: @Ver Nick Похоже, какая-то ерунда происходит с сайтом. У меня мгновенно появились голоса за 15 ответов

Comment: Кто вам сказал?

Comment: Просто все ваши ответы очень простые и понятные, почему бы за них и не поставить голос вверх?

Comment: Просто сейчас заметил

Comment: Потому что они и были сейчас поставлены :)

Comment: Так это Ваша работа? Вряд ли стоит так делать.

Comment: А кто мне что скажет? Понравились ответы — я поставил плюс. Не понравились — поставил минус.

Comment: Думаю, что есть система, отслеживающая массовое голосование одного за ответы другого.

Comment: Да, такое есть, но я проголосовал частично. Надеюсь, ничего не будет.

Comment: Хорошие ответы заслуживают репутации.

Comment: @Ver Nick Система функционирует :)  −80 [Массовое голосование отменено](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

Comment: @Ver Nick Опять твоя работа +3 старых вопроса? Перестань, пожалуйста.